# Redis as a cache for MySQL writes

Tags: php, mysql, redis

I'm looking to add a **runtime config** for my app which when toggled on will redirect all writes from MySQL to Redis. A different script will poll Redis to make these inserts to MySQL at a later time, manually.

I need this for times when we don't want any updates to the MySQL DB (a write request on a Slave machine, DB downtime, etc).

A typical request to our app would result in ~ 3 insert queries and contain data such as `User submitted data, IP address, date/time`.

I've considered 3 options, listed below in the order of simplicity (for me):

1.**Store raw SQL for the insert in a Redis** list, and 2nd script will pop these out and carry out inserts to MySQL

```
INSERT INTO DB.TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

2.**Store JSON encoded array of variables necessary** for insert along with data (columns => values), DB and Table name. The 2nd script just needs to explode these values as columns and values and carry out insert.

```
{
"db":"DB",
"table":"table",
"data":[
  {
  "col1":"val1",
  "col2":"val2"
  }
 ]
}
```

3.**Store all variables required from the app** in a Hash object in Redis. 2nd script goes through the complete logic of getting an insert query.

```
{
"ipAddress":"127.0.0.1",
"requestType":"hmm",
"variable2": "a"
...
}
```

While the 1st seems the least painful, it doesn't seem right in that it appears too hacky and..unsafe. Will there be lost / malformed data by storing it this way?

What do you recommend I do?

Comment: What do you do about the _queries_ (that is, not updates)?

Comment: If it's a downtime, they can read from a slave on another machine. Otherwise, they will continue reading from MySQL.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev another use-case where we need this. A geographically distributed API endpoint where writes must only go to Master and update requests on the Slaves are cached in redis and relayed back to Master. Here, MySQL master-master replication didn't work too well. Hence this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need my writes to tolerate temporary DB downtime, I pass them through a background job queue.

1. Frontend receives a request from user and figures out that it needs to make a write.
2. That write is pushed into a queue
3. Later on, a background worker pops data about that write and tries to execute it. Now, if the DB is down, it'll simply re-schedule the write (or not ACK it, depending on capabilities of the queue).

This most closely resembles your option #3, I think.

Note that this scenario means that all writes always go through the queue. Alleviates the need for manual intervention. When main DB goes down at 4 AM, you don't expect to wake up and change app config, all in under a second?

Comment: Thanks. We use beanstalkd extensively for background writes as well. However, in our scenario Redis works quicker for multiple writes (pipelining) and it's strings are apparently binary safe unlike beanstalkd's. Is there anything explicitly wrong in going with options 1 / 2? They just remove the complexity of our background workers at the moment.

Comment: @kouton, data is more "workable". What if you find yourself later needing to not execute a part of those staged writes (for whatever reason)? If it's stored as data, it's trivial. If it's sql, now you have to analyze it. I'd say, do whatever is easier. If your redis is compromised, you're screwed anyway :)

Comment: Makes sense. Option 2 seems to offer the best of both worlds at the moment. Thanks.